# Using CTE in Python with Postgresql and psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a query using CTE where I am creating 2 subtables and then the select statement. I believe the following syntax would work for full SQL, but it isn't working in this situation using psycopg2 in Python.

The idea is that I should be able to pull a query that shows the Name of all events (E.Event), the E.EDate, the E.ETemp and SmithTime. So it should have the full list of Events but the time column only shows times recorded for Smith (not in all Events).

```
query = ("""WITH cte AS (SELECT E.Event, O.Time AS "SmithTime"
            FROM event E JOIN outcome O ON E.EventID = O.EventID
                        JOIN name N ON N.ID = O.ID
            WHERE Name = 'Smith'),

WITH cte2 AS (SELECT E.Event, O.Time, E.EDate, E.ETemp
    FROM event E JOIN outcome O ON E.EventID = O.EventID
                        JOIN name N ON N.ID = O.ID)
                
SELECT cte2.Event, cte2.EDate, cte2.ETemp, cte.SmithTime
    FROM cte JOIN cte2 ON cte.Event = cte2.Event
    ORDER BY 2 ASC""")

query = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
print(query)
```

This is just my latest iteration, I'm not sure what else to try. It is currently generating a DatabaseError:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'WITH cte AS (SELECT E.Event, O.Time AS "SmithTime"
            FROM event E JOIN outcome O ON E.EventID = O.EventID
                        JOIN name N ON N.ID = O.ID
            WHERE Name = 'Smith'),

WITH cte2 AS (SELECT E.Event, O.Time, E.EDate, E.ETemp
    FROM event E JOIN outcome O ON E.EventID = O.EventID
                        JOIN name N ON N.ID = O.ID)
                
SELECT cte2.Event, cte2.EDate, cte2.ETemp, cte.SmithTime
    FROM cte JOIN cte2 ON cte.Event = cte2.Event
    ORDER BY 2 ASC': syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 6: WITH cte2 AS (SELECT E.Event, O.Time, E.EDate, E.ETemp
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  When you say it isn't working, does that mean that the script has some error, or that the script runs but generates the wrong output?

Comment: Apologies, it generates a Database Error. I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether or not your current query even be logically correct.  But we can get around the SQL error by inlining the common table expressions:

```sql
SELECT cte2.Event, cte2.EDate, cte2.ETemp, cte.SmithTime
FROM (
    SELECT E.Event, O.Time AS "SmithTime"
    FROM event E
    INNER JOIN outcome O ON E.EventID = O.EventID
    INNER JOIN name N ON N.ID = O.ID
    WHERE Name = 'Smith'
) cte
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT E.Event, O.Time, E.EDate, E.ETemp
    FROM event E
    INNER JOIN outcome O ON E.EventID = O.EventID
    INNER JOIN name N ON N.ID = O.ID
) cte2
    ON cte.Event = cte2.Event
ORDER BY 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an SQL syntax error, nothing specific to psycopg2.

There's only one `WITH` in a CTE query. It should be `WITH cte AS (...), cte2 AS (...) SELECT ...`, not `WITH cte AS (...), WITH cte2 AS (...) SELECT ...`.

Comment: That is what I just did, and it almost works correctly. The only issue now is that it is only listing out events that have a "SmithTime", but it needs to list all Events